# How to automatically set certain row values in CSV import into Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models - Transaction and Bank. Every transaction belongs to a bank.

In my Bank show view file - I have an table with all the transactions, relating to that bank account. I have created an import function in my Transaction model class which works well but I need to set certain rows to specific functions.

The CSV import within my transaction is:

```
def self.import(file)
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
  Transaction.create! row.to_hash
 end
end
```

Controller looks like:

```
def import
  Transaction.import(params[:file], bank_id, current_user_id)
  redirect_to :back, notice: "Tramsactions imported."
  end
```

This works well, however because there is many bank accounts, each transaction needs to have a bank_account_id and user_id. I need to bank_account_id to be set from where the user is importing the file. So if the import occurs within Bank id: 1 - the import will automatically set the bank account value to 1. And I am not sure how to set the user_id to equal the current user_id?

Answer (score 1):

you should pass bank_id and current_user_id to this function and then you can use the following code,

```
def self.import(file, bank_id, current_user_id)
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
    transaction_params = row.to_hash.merge!({bank_id: bank_id, user_id: current_user_id})
    Transaction.create! transaction_params
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Krupa :) But how would I set the bank_id to be there current bank_id the user is in?

Comment: Can you please share your controller code and routes?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely you can not get `current_user` at model layer, as session variables are not accessible to model layer, so you would need to pass `current_user` and `bank_id`

Just a side note to boost your import functionality.

[ActiveRecord.import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/wiki)

```
def self.import(file, bank_id, current_user_id)
  transactions = []
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
    transaction_params = row.to_hash.merge!({bank_id: bank_id, user_id: current_user_id})
    transactions << Transaction.new(transaction_params)
  end
  Transaction.import(transactions) 
end
```

Just have a look at these [benchmarks](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/wiki/Benchmarks) to get a sense of just how much faster this option is. Instead of separate transactions, commits, and inserts that a  Model.create generates SQL for, this handles it in a single query.

References: -

https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/wiki

https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/wiki/Requiring

https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activerecord-import/ActiveRecord/Base

Comment: Thanks Gabbar. When I tried implementing this, It gives me the error: ```wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 3)``` It refers to the (file, bank_id, current_user_id) params. Any idea why it would do this?

Comment: @JeanMalan Could you show the code at controller side where you are calling `Transaction.import(..)`, and i guess its giving error cause you haven't pass `bank_id`, and `current_user_id` at controller side, please cross check it it should be `Transaction.import(file, bank_id, current_user_id)` ?

Comment: I've updated the controller and updated my post. Not sure that I am passing those through properly

Comment: @JeanMalan Have you assigned value of `current_user_id = current_user.id` and `bank_id = bank_id` for which transactions will be done?

Comment: Well, thats where I am getting stuck, I dont know how to set the current bank_id, which the user is in, as the params.

Comment: @JeanMalan Actually i'm not aware of your model structure, and i think you will get current_user as if user is logged in then devise provides helped to get current_user so you can set `current_user_id = current_user.id` also user should have a `bank_id` then you can get `bank_id = current_user.bank_id` or you should get bank_id from your from altogether with params[:file]. hopefully this make sense. please let me know for further guidance.

Comment: @JeanMalan Just to make sure were you able to solve this issue? please do let me know for further guidance.